# GCC 4.9.2 issues - linking error "start" symbol undefined (after yosemite update)

Tags: gcc, homebrew, osx-yosemite

So, I upgraded to Yosemite and also updated gcc to gcc-4.9. Now nothing works. Even a basic C program like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main() {
    printf("woh!");
}
```

The details of `gcc -v a.c` is below. The basic error is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my configuration for CC, clang and gcc.

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-4.9 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew gcc 4.9.2' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues --enable-plugin --disable-nls --enable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Homebrew gcc 4.9.2)
```

I had created links for gcc to gcc-4.9 which was installed successfully using Homebrew. I have run `brew doctor` and received no issues. Command Line Tools was updated using `code-select -install`

```
Gautams-MacBook-Pro:~ gautamrege$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/gcc
lrwxrwxr-x  1 gautamrege  admin  22 Nov 14 20:14 /usr/local/bin/gcc@ -> /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9
Gautams-MacBook-Pro:~ gautamrege$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 
lrwxrwxr-x  1 gautamrege  admin  31 Nov 14 20:14 /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9@ -> ../Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/bin/gcc-4.9
```

These are my CC and clang versions (basically the same)

```
Gautams-MacBook-Pro:~ gautamrege$ CC -v
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
Gautams-MacBook-Pro:~ gautamrege$ clang -c
clang: error: no input files
Gautams-MacBook-Pro:~ gautamrege$ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Finally, here is the detailed log using `gcc -v`.

```
$ gcc -v a.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-4.9 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew gcc 4.9.2' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues --enable-plugin --disable-nls --enable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Homebrew gcc 4.9.2) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.10.0' '-v' '-mtune=core2'
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/cc1 -quiet -v -D__DYNAMIC__ a.c -fPIC -quiet -dumpbase a.c -mmacosx-version-min=10.10.0 -mtune=core2 -auxbase a -version -o /var/folders/dr/kc0cps51533gqx5zm8gv33x80000gn/T//ccvx7Ydq.s
GNU C (Homebrew gcc 4.9.2) version 4.9.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.9.2, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.2-p10, MPC version 1.0.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/include-fixed
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks
 /Library/Frameworks
End of search list.
GNU C (Homebrew gcc 4.9.2) version 4.9.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.9.2, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.2-p10, MPC version 1.0.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: f90e36a64a568856fa161772b1b4076f
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.10.0' '-v' '-mtune=core2'
 as -arch x86_64 -force_cpusubtype_ALL -o /var/folders/dr/kc0cps51533gqx5zm8gv33x80000gn/T//cckdbo1t.o /var/folders/dr/kc0cps51533gqx5zm8gv33x80000gn/T//ccvx7Ydq.s
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.10.0' '-v' '-mtune=core2'
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/collect2 -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o a.out -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../.. /var/folders/dr/kc0cps51533gqx5zm8gv33x80000gn/T//cckdbo1t.o -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem -v
collect2 version 4.9.2
/usr/bin/ld -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o a.out -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../.. /var/folders/dr/kc0cps51533gqx5zm8gv33x80000gn/T//cckdbo1t.o -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-136
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64
Library search paths:
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/lib
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm pretty sure I am making some basic mistake.Needless to day, *all* other package installations are failing because of this same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have your xcode fully installed and up to date?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Nope - I have updated only the Xcode command line tools. `brew doctor` does complain about updating Xcode and I have Xcode 4.6.2 as I never need it. I'm assuming you are going to ask me to update that, so I'll do so and update the post here :)

Comment: Please at least use `xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/` so that e.g. `clang` invokes the XCode 6 clang.

Comment: @TimSmith You nailed it. Only change is that this particular command needs to as sudo. I'll wait for you to answer this question, so you get credit. Otherwise, I'll answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Copying information from comments to this Community Wiki answer.*</sup>

[Tim Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892260/tim-smith) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182769/gcc-4-9-2-issues-linking-error-start-symbol-undefined-after-yosemite-update#comment42891885_27182769) that the key to this problem is to run:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

This makes sure that `clang` invokes the XCode 6 version of `clang`.